# WSO2 MDM Encrypt sensitive information in .json configuration files

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I cannot find a way to encrypt the keystore password in the json configuration files that are used in the WSO2 EMM. 
There is a notable documentation for encryption of the sensitive information in the xml configuration files for the EMM product, but nothing for the json configuration files.

My question is about encrypting the keystore password in the json configuration files.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

Secure vault uses the xpath to specify the location that we want to encrypt. Therefore currently secure vault does not support encrypting .json and properties files.